# Is it possible to have more than one custom tab for the office ribbon?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, ribbon

I can not find any documentation to verify this or any working examples

I want to achieve something like this xml below, but I think this really is not possible.

```
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2010/01/customui">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabAddIns" label="Ribbon1">
      </tab>

      <tab idMso="TabAddIns" label="Ribbon2">
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>

</customUI>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can have multiple tabs, if you are using exiting tabs then set `idMso="exiting tabids"`

Existing tab ids should be valid ids which can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=2451)

If you are using your own custom tabs then use `id="customtab1"` instead of idMso

customtab1 - can be any valid strings

**EDITED**

The below ribbon xml worked

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabAddIns" label="Ribbon1">
        <group id="MyGroup"
               label="My Group">
        </group>
      </tab>
      <tab id="CustomAddin" label="Ribbon2">
      <group id="CustomAddinGroup"
             label="My Group">
      </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Try using Ribbon designer and convert to XML and make sure you add the below code in ThisAddin.cs file

```
protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
{
   return new Ribbon1();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `idMso` for `id` and give your tabs a custom name.

```
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2010/01/customui">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="Tab1" label="Ribbon1">
      </tab>

      <tab id="Tab2" label="Ribbon2">
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>

</customUI>
```

`idMso` is used to refer to Microsoft Objects that already exists within the application hosting the ribbon.

Comment: That didn't seem to work either, do you have a link or an example of this working in word?

Comment: I've used it myself in Excel. I'll see if I can get something for you when I get home.

Comment: Tab with "id" instead of "isMso" works well for me. It is not possible to define "isMso" twice. It will override the Tab "add-ins". Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have two tabs with the same id (idMso="TabAddIns"). Make sure the ids are unique.

Comment: What does not work? Do you get an error? Did you turn on addin errors in Outlook options?