# Cant have a Excel Add in as a separate tab from an enabled COM Add in

Tags: excel, vsto, excel-addins

Currently I have an Excel Add In in Excel 2016 called 'Excel Image Assistant' (https://excel-image-assistant.com/). This is an excel add-in currently enabled on my excel and appears under a tab on the ribbon as Add-Ins.

I have developed a VSTO Add In which I want to install on my machine and enable this personalized bespoke ribbon. It installs perfectly fine, however when I enable this COM add in. The items from the excel add in now appears in my COM ADD IN ribbon.

I want to treat these as two different tabs but it seems as though the excel add in is conflicting with the VSTO COM Add In.

So you can only have one or the other enabled to see the add in Excel but if you have both enabled the Excel Add in is put in my COM add in.

Is this in the VSTO Code that could be causing this? Or this is something in Excel settings wise that may need to be adjusted to allow both of these to be enabled as different tabs in the ribbon as i need them treated seperately.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370321/is-it-possible-to-have-more-than-one-custom-tab-for-the-office-ribbon

Comment: Answered in above stack overflow:  <tab id="TabAddInsA"> rather than using idMSO which is the default Add Ins Tab

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have more than one custom tab for the office ribbon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370321/is-it-possible-to-have-more-than-one-custom-tab-for-the-office-ribbon)